# DefaultSchedulerService in ASP.NET application

Tags: windows, asp.net-3.5, workflow-foundation

My project has a requirement to implement look-ahead caching i.e. triggering another request on invokation of a specific request. The following details in short the implementation -

1. HttpModule parses the SOAPRequest and matches entry in a configuration file for look-ahead candidate.
2. If the request matches, it prepares the Parameters dictionary and starts appropriate workflow.
3. Single workflow runtime is used across all requests is ensured through initializing the runtime instance at Application_Start event and stored in Application Dictionary.
4. Using persistence service and DefaultScheduler service.

We can't implement windows service model, as current requirement mandates passing the SOAPRequest parameters as arguments. ManualSchedulerService is not in contention due to synchronous nature of it's actual behaviour. Still the performance is pretty bad and product team is not happy. Can anybody suggest me better solution?

Thanks,
Samir

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this [ASP.NET Service](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNETService.aspx) Or look at [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) a full-featured, open source job scheduling system that can be used from smallest apps to large scale enterprise systems.

Comment: Unfortunately as explained in the description, the operation are unlike normal jobs i.e. send email or log entry. The request actually invokes internal web-services and after retrieving data is stored in database.